# Refactor fields numeric calcs

Tags: qgis

I can't make the same calcs i do while editing a shapefile, like multiplying one field by a real number.

My qgis version is 2.18.17 and i'm writting:

***[("FIELD1" *100) + "FIELD2" ]*** on Expression Dialog and the output preview returns ***"Expression Invalid"***.

Comment: Probably a [bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17170).  From the timing of fix (Apr. 2018), version 2.18.19 and later would be ok. A quick test by 2.18.20 (on Windows 10) worked for me.